# Most efficient pair-value data structure in Python with support for duplicates and sorting?

Tags: python, data-structures

What is the most efficient pair-value data structure in Python with support for duplicates and sorting?

I need a dictionary like structure but it must support duplicates, I am looking a solution that could be sorted fast based in the first value of each pair.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "support duplicates"?  It almost sounds like you just want a list of tuples... (Though lookup won't be efficient in that case.)

Comment: Yes, it is a silly question. I am using a list of tuples now, I dont need to perform lookups but I would like to know if there is something with a similar interface that a dictionary (i.e.: retrieve only the keys or first values in this case).

Comment: It's not a silly question at all! I just wasn't perfectly clear on what you were asking when I first read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a sorted list using the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. With a list `data`, for each new pair `(a,b)`, `data.insert` at the index returned by `bisect(data,(a,LARGE_NUMBER))` to add a new entry after all existing entries starting with `a`. The list is always maintained in sorted order, so you don't worry about "sorting fast".

```
>>> from bisect import bisect
>>> from random import randint
>>> data = []
>>> for x in range(20):
...   a,b = randint(1,10),randint(1,100)
...   data.insert(bisect(data,(a,1000)),(a,b))
...
>>> for d in data: print (d)
...
(1, 67)
(1, 85)
(1, 38)
(2, 78)
(3, 57)
(3, 37)
(4, 76)
(4, 74)
(5, 47)
(5, 24)
(5, 59)
(5, 91)
(6, 85)
(6, 41)
(7, 18)
(7, 41)
(7, 24)
(9, 48)
(9, 77)
(9, 82)
(10, 80)
```

Comment: Nice! On a side note, sorting is faster than inserting at an arbitrary index. It depends on the OP's use case, but it may make a lot more sense to just build things up and sort at the end (or after each batch of `append`s) unless the OP needs the sequence to _always_ be in a sorted state.

Comment: Thanks! The method `bisect.insort` fits my needs. For my user case it works better than sorting because I have to do multiple inserts, manipulate the list that must be sorted, do more inserts and sort it again.

Comment: `bisect.insort` will also sort on the second value of the pair, which you indicated was not significant for the sort. That's why I didn't use it. But you know your requirements better than I!